# which android studio version have Android 5.1 (API level 22)?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have downloaded some projects of android apk to learn from it ..
i try to open it using the latest version of android studio (2.2.3) , but it's take too long time and then stop ,I looked for a solution to this problem and found that these applications were built on previous versions of the sdk So to solve this problem, I should use an earlier version of Android Studio, so I want to know what is the Android studio version which have Android 5.1 (API level 22).

Comment: "I should use an earlier version of Android Studio" -- no. "so I want to know what is the Android studio version which have Android 5.1 (API level 22)" -- yours does, once you download it from the SDK Manager.

Comment: when you try to open old android project in android android studio also downloads the necessary files and previous build for you so try to make sure it Android studio downloads the files completely otherwise it will not able to open

Comment: I have downloaded all the needed files .... but I asked who create those projects ,and he told me that I really need to install Android 5.1 (API level 22). so If any one know which android studio version comes with those API Level please tell me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a single installation of Android Studio and all the SDKs you want to use (partially or fully installed)

[image]

Comment: yes but because I have the latest version of android studio there is only two item in this list (Android 7.1.1 & Android 7.0).So how can I get a previous SDK version?

Comment: this is the latest AS: 2.2.3

Comment: yes .... but I need an older sdk version .so from where can I get it except using sdk manager?, because my sdk manager does n't have this sdk

Answer (score 0):

You have to download  the sdk via sdk manager download  the latest sdk

Comment: I have the latest sdk ,but some projects need a previous sdk version so it can open